# How can I slice a CVPixelBuffer in the middle to have two CVPixelBuffers? (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-image

I am receiving data from server, and then it is turned into CVPixelBuffer without my control via another module I use. This buffer has two images, which are glued together. Second image is under the first one when I preview the buffer. I want to slice this buffer right in the middle to have two separate CVPixelBuffers, each containing one of those images. Is there any way to do this without converting the buffer to other image types? (Like constructing two other buffers using each half of original buffer bytes)

Comment: Do you necessarily need two `CVPixelBuffers` as output, or would you convert those anyway?

Comment: I need those as buffers, and will pass those to my shaders to use one as overlay and the other one for filtering purposes.

Comment: You could pass the same (combined) buffer to both shaders and adjust the sampling coordinates so that each only samples the needed part. This way, you don't need to copy any pixels to other buffers.

Comment: Okay, I will check if I can do that. Thank you.